# Why is MongoDB ignoring some of my updates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've been building an application in Node.JS using the native MongoDB driver - it includes contacts, and when a user accepts a contact, it should remove from "pending" and "sent" contacts, then add to "contacts".

Example code and documents:

```
    /*
=============================
User "john"
=============================
{
  username: "john",
  contacts: ["jim"],
  pending_contacts: ["bob"]
}

=============================
User "bob"
=============================
{
  username: "bob",
  contacts: ["dave"],
  sent_contacts: ["john"]
}

=============================
What SHOULD happen
=============================
{
  username: "bob",
  contacts: ["dave", "john"],
  sent_contacts: []
},
{
  username: "john",
  contacts: ["jim", "bob"],
  pending_contacts: []
}

=============================
What ACTUALLY happens
=============================
{
  username: "john",
  contacts: ["jim", "bob"],
  pending_contacts: ["bob"]
},
{
  username: "bob",
  contacts: ["dave", "john"],
  sent_contacts: ["john"]
}

*/

  var col = this.db.collection('users');
  var contact = "bob", username = "john";
  var who = [contact, username];
  var finishCount = 0;
  // finish will run 3 times before callback
  function finish(name) {
    console.log(name, ' has finished');
    finishCount++;
    if(finishCount<3) return;
    callback(false, null);
  }
  // run if there's an error
  function failed(err) {
    callback(err, null)
  }
  console.log('removing %s and %s from pending and sent', username, contact)
  col.update(
    {username: { $in: who }},
    {
      $pullAll: {
        sent_contacts: who,
        pending_contacts: who
      }
    }, {multi: 1},
    function(err,data) {
      if(err) return failed(err);
      finish('REMOVE_CONTACTS');
    }
  );
  col.update(
    {username: username}, {$addToSet: {contacts: contact}},
    function(err,res) {
      if(err) return failed(err);
      console.log('added 1');
      finish('ADD_TO_USER');
    }
  );
  col.update(
    {username: contact}, {$addToSet: {contacts: username}},
    function(err,res) {
      if(err) return failed(err);
      console.log('added 2');
      finish('ADD_TO_CONTACT');
    }
  );
```

The first update removes the contact and the owner from each-others pending/sent list, the second and third update add the owner to the contact's contact list and vice versa.

The issue is, the final result appears to be as if the removal never happened, though the removal query works perfectly fine by itself. I don't know if this is a problem with MongoDB itself (or if it's intended), or if it's an issue with the driver, so I hope someone can at least clarify this for me.

**NOTE:** Yes I know they run asynchronously. Running them one after the other by putting each update in the previous callback does NOT make a difference. Before anyone complains about how awful this code looks, I previously had it set up within Async.JS but I removed it from this code sample to ensure that Asyn.cJS was not responsible for the issues.

Comment: Please include your relevant code in the question.

Comment: @DaveNewton It was on the gist, but I've put it into the actual question now

Comment: @JohnnyHK If I run them one after the other by putting each within the previous callback, the issue still happens. MongoDB doesn't seem to care about the order at all

Comment: @Someguy123 Your code produced the "What SHOULD happen" result when I tried it. That was using v2.0.34 of the MongoDB driver.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I just updated from 2.0.33 to 2.0.34 and seems to have made no difference. Noted some odd behaviour though, it seems to remove from pending_contacts on the first user, but if it's in sent_contacts instead, it will not remove (even though the query targets both keys). Note: I'm using MongoLab for the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the node native driver this works for me every time:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    async = require('async'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var user = "john",
    contact  = "bob";

var contactsList = [
  {
    "username": "john",
    "contacts": [
      "jim"
    ],
    "pending_contacts": [
      "bob"
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "bob",
    "contacts": [
      "dave"
    ],
    "sent_contacts": [
      "john"
    ]
  }
];

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {

  var coll = db.collection("contacts");

  async.series(
    [
      // Wipe clean
      function(callback) {
        coll.remove({},callback)
      },

      // Init collection
      function(callback) {
        async.each(contactsList,function(contact,callback) {
          coll.insert(contact,callback);
        },callback);
      },

      // Do updates
      function(callback) {
        // Init batch
        var bulk = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

        // Add to user and pull from pending
        bulk.find({
          "username": user,
          "contacts": { "$ne": contact },
        }).updateOne({
          "$push": { "contacts": contact },
          "$pull": { "pending_contacts": contact }
        });

        // Add to contact and pull from sent
        bulk.find({
          "username": contact,
          "contacts": { "$ne": user },
          "sent_contacts": user
        }).updateOne({
          "$push": { "contacts": user },
          "$pull": { "sent_contacts": user }
        });

        // Execute
        bulk.execute(function(err,response) {
          console.log( response.toJSON() );
          callback(err);
        });

      },

      // List collection
      function(callback) {
        coll.find({}).toArray(function(err,results) {
          console.log(results);
          callback(err);
        });
      }

    ],
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      db.close();
    }

  );

});
```

And the output:

```
{ ok: 1,
  writeErrors: [],
  writeConcernErrors: [],
  insertedIds: [],
  nInserted: 0,
  nUpserted: 0,
  nMatched: 2,
  nModified: 2,
  nRemoved: 0,
  upserted: [] }
[ { _id: 55b0c16934fadce812cdcf9d,
    username: 'john',
    contacts: [ 'jim', 'bob' ],
    pending_contacts: [] },
  { _id: 55b0c16934fadce812cdcf9e,
    username: 'bob',
    contacts: [ 'dave', 'john' ],
    sent_contacts: [] } ]
```

Improvements here are basically to use the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) and send all updates at once to the server and get a single response. Also note the use of operators in the updates and the query selection as well.

Simply put, you already know the "user" as well as the "contact" they are accepting. The contact to be accepted is "pending" and the contact themselves have the user in "sent".

These are really just simple [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operations on either array as is appropriate. Rather than using [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) here, the query conditions make sure that the expected values are present when performing the update. This also preserves "order" which `$addToSet` can basically not guarantee, because it's a "set", which is un-ordered.

One send to the server and one callback response, leaving both users updated correctly. Makes more sense then sending multiple updates and waiting for the callback response from each.

Anyhow, this is a complete self contained listing with only the two named dependencies, so you can easily run it yourself and confirm the results.

---

When I say "Complete and self contained" it means start a new project and simply run the code. Here's the complete instruction:

```
mkdir sample
cd sample
npm init
npm install mongodb --save
npm install async --save
```

Then create a file with the code listing in that folder, say `test.js` and then run:

```
node test.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response, but strangely enough sent_contacts and pending_contacts didn't get changed, despite using your exact code. This is the result from the execution which is odd because it looks as if it worked fine (yet the two contacts both have unaltered sent/pending): `{ ok: 1,
  writeErrors: [],
  writeConcernErrors: [],
  insertedIds: [],
  nInserted: 0,
  nUpserted: 0,
  nMatched: 2,
  nModified: 2,
  nRemoved: 0,
  upserted: [],
  lastOp: { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1437701814 } }`

Comment: @Someguy123 You are either not running the standalone listing that is here or there is something wrong with your install. Nonetheless the "WriteResponse" you quote there disagrees with your "doesn't change" claim. The `nModified` there clearly shows 2, which **only** happens when changes actually occur. Be sure to run the "whole" listing independantly and on a different collection to your existing one. That is why the data is "self contained". See the addiional instruction.

Comment: I've tested it 100% standalone and it seems to work. I've given you the bounty since I don't think anyone else is going to respond to this. I'm really confused to why it doesn't work in my Express application since I'm using the exact same version of Async, MongoClient etc. I suppose I'll have to do a lot of investigation by myself since there's **very little difference** between my applications implementation of that code and that standalone code other than it being behind a route... If you have any idea of what could possibly interfere with this, let me know, thanks.

Comment: @Someguy123 There are quite a few differences. 1. The operations are in "bulk" so there is only one request to the server required for this process. 2. Moving to bulk avoids the async callback confusion that is one likely cause of your problems. 3. The operations themselves are in a more concise form than you had them, reducing to the "two" operations that are only required. 4. You saw yourself that "two" items were updated where you say they are not. Chances are you are looking at the wrong items and have "multiple" records for the "user" names. Always use "unique" identifiers.

Comment: There are no duplicate users. Also I was referring to the code that I copied from your post and implemented into my application. Oddly enough, it does something that makes no sense: it adds the contact to contacts on each side, however the contact will switch from pending_contacts to sent_contacts, and vice versa for the opposite contact. Tested on both a local instance and MongoLabs. How is this happening? There is nothing else that interacts with the database on this route...